# Created a Windows service from a Jar file using NSSM, it runs as a process but doesn't run the program

Tags: java, service, jar, pdfbox, nssm

I created a Windows Service from a .jar from NSSM using a batch file.  I exported my code from eclipse as a jar file. With Library handling: Extract required libraries into generated jar.

The program uses java's WatchService to check if a file is created in a folder. It also uses Apache PDFBox API to modify the PDF that was created in the folder.

I was able to make the jar file to run as Window's service but does not modify the PDF.  The jar file alone runs correctly but when it is a service it does nothing.

This is how I created the service:

```
pushd "<path to jar>"
nssm.exe install "<service Name>" "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe" -jar <jar name>
nssm.exe set "<service Name>" AppDirectory "<path to jar>"
```

The program is expected to open the PDF and add text fields to the top the PDF.
The actual results is that the service does nothing.

Update:
The reason why the Window Service is not displaying the JOptionPane is because the service runs in the background not allowing the JOptionPane to show up.

```
Allow service to interact with desktop
```

The selection above does not allow the JOptionPane to show up.

Comment: This is the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296949/how-to-allow-joptionpanes-to-show-in-a-windows-service